# append a string to a parameter in YAML style

Tags: symfony

*The main goal is to avoid creating another parameter*

The `parameters.yml` has the following line:

```
base_url: /v2/frontend/
```

I need to add the frontal controller if the website is running on the `dev` environment.

I tried overwriting it in `config_dev.yml` but a `ParameterCircularReferenceException` has been raised

```
base_url: %base_url%/app_dev.php
```

I tried to do it in an extension in my bundle `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension`

**MyExtension**

```
class MyExtension extends \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension
{
     public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) 
     {
          ....
          if ('dev' === $c->getParameter('kernel.environment') && $c->getParameter('kernel.debug')) {
              $baseUrl = $container->getParameter('base_url');

              $container->setParameter('base_url', $baseUrl . '/' . $c->getParameter('frontalcontroller'));
          }
          // $container->getParameter('base_url') is updated here
     }
```

But when I injected `base_url` in a service, I realized that `base_url` has not changed, it always contains the initial value set in the `parameters.yml`

How do I edit parameters values dynamically as we can do in [php](/questions/tagged/php) for instance

```
$v = 'value';
$v .= '_appended';
// $v === 'value_appended' at this stage
```

> symfony 2.6

Comment: You could split the parameter in two params: `base_url_prefix` and `base_url_postfix` so you can override in the config_dev.yml:

Comment: @Matteo That's what I'm doing so far, but I don't get it why even when I edit my parameter in a DI extension it does not change